# Only half of the universe have the chance to answer this [Spoilers]

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> My prefix can be seen in "three things that think"
>
> My infix is used for vowels
>
> And my suffix can be seen in a computer

**I can wipeout half of the universe, Who am I?**

Comment: from the last clue perhaps the break at Nazaré

Comment: Nice puzzle, especially after having seen the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fictional character

> Thanos, whose ambition in the Infinity Wars movie was to wipe out half the universe’s life, with the goal of environmental sustainability.

Prefix:

> th(ree) th(ings) th(at) th(ink)

Infix:

> ‘an’ used instead of ‘a’, before words starting with a vowel sound

Suffix:

> OS (a computer’s Operating System)

Comment: That's a spoiler to two things! Talk about misrepresentation! :-O